# All CDK commands are stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Hope somebody has some tips or experience with this problem. All the cdk commands on my computer suddenly stopped working, cdk list, cdk deploy, bootstrap etc.

They all get stuck on the same step when I run it with -vv

```
[11:06:15] outdir: cdk.out
[11:06:15] env: {
  CDK_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1',
  CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT: 'xxxxxxxx',
  CDK_OUTDIR: 'cdk.out',
  CDK_CLI_ASM_VERSION: '31.0.0',
  CDK_CLI_VERSION: '2.70.0'
}
```

When I run --verbose it gets stuck on:

```
[11:27:15] Notices refreshed
```

Things I tried:

- Downgrading / reinstalling cdk
- Reconfiguring my .aws credentials
- Running the repo on linux / windows
- Deleting cdk.out / cdk.context.json
- Deleting the stack
- CDK init in another directory seems to work

One other thing to note is that when I deploy it to my project with the gitlab pipeline the cdk deploy works. So it is some local caching/cdk issue I think but I can't seem to solve it.

Any help / tips would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning my project again seemed to fix the issue. It then broke when I npm installed in my nodejs lambda layer folder.
In my cdk project I had a nodejs folder with a lambda layer, this package package.json had a dependency:

```
"projectname": "file:../../.."
```

I thought it was weird and removed it, now the deploy works fine again.